# How to add horizontal line between charts

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I'm trying to add horizontal line in HTML generated with bokeh.
I tried to use following code:

```
 horizontal_div = Div(text="<hr>")
 tmp_charts = list()
 for chart in charts:
     tmp_charts.append(horizontal_div)
     tmp_charts.append(chart)
   
 fig = column(list(tmp_charts))
```

where charts contains list with multiple bar charts

I'm getting correct list with Divs added but horizontal lines are missing in browser.
How can I add them and get them in browser?

Comment: this is probably related to the styling of the generated html and css. Could you also share that?

Comment: I'm using one of the examples I found on web: https://pastebin.com/S9iK22Gr